# How Can I Tell Which Licences I Am Using In Jars?

Tags: java

I have a classpath of over 250 jars and I have been asked to report on the licences in use.

Some jars have the license in the META-INF so I could scan for that.

Others are listed on maven e.g. https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0 ("Public" license) so maybe that could be scraped.

Is there an easy way of doing this rather than checking each file manually?

E.g. is there an existing script or a maven plugin for instance?

I found this groovy script that is able to scan jars and find them in maven
https://github.com/myspotontheweb/ant2ivy which is one of the building blocks for writing an automated process for this.

Comment: Thanks for finding that. I'm not sure why it didn't come up in my searches.